# Error in assigning formula to a column using the F-strings

Tags: python, excel, string, excel-formula, xlwings

I needed to replace few columns in the raw data sheet (pivot from this sheet) with formulas. 
I have used Xlwings package to do this and it succeeds for other formulas, but not this particular one.

These formulas work;

```
#column Y: Year 1-FA   #Works perfectly
sheet_obj.range("Y2:Y"+str(max_row)).formula = f'=IF(NUMBERVALUE(C2)=1,CONCAT("Y1-",L2),L2)'
    
#column z: custom    #Works perfectly
sheet_obj.range("Z2:Z"+str(max_row)).formula = f'=CONCAT(B2,"-",E2,"-",I2,"-",J2,"-",K2)'
```

This following returns errors;

```
#column P: New Out of PP   #this is whwre the it shows error
    sheet_obj.range("P2:P"+str(max_row)).formula = f'''=IFERROR(IF(OR(O2<>"",O2<>"NULL"),IF(OR(J2="Term 1",J2="Term 33"),O2+MIN(XLOOKUP(CONCAT(N2,C2,J2,H2),Subject_Map!$G:$G,Subject_Map!$H:$H,"",0),Raw(Merged)!S2),O2),O2),O2)'''
```

formula I want to assign is

```
'=IFERROR(IF(OR(O2<>"",O2<>"NULL"),IF(OR(J2="Term 1",J2="Term 33"),O2+MIN(XLOOKUP(CONCAT(N2,C2,J2,H2),Subject_Map!$G:$G,Subject_Map!$H:$H,"",0),Raw(Merged)!S2),O2),O2),O2)'
```

Comment: could you please format your code?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the sheet name `Raw(Merged)`, you need to put single quote around it, `'Raw(Merged)'!S2`:

```
sheet_obj.range("P2:P"+str(max_row)).formula = '''=IFERROR(IF(OR(O2<>"",O2<>"NULL"),IF(OR(J2="Term 1",J2="Term 33"),O2+MIN(XLOOKUP(CONCAT(N2,C2,J2,H2),Subject_Map!$G:$G,Subject_Map!$H:$H,"",0),'Raw(Merged)'!S2),O2),O2),O2)'''
```

Comment: @rachel_ust: it isn't the sheet name! As there is no space between 'Raw(Merged)' quotes aren't necessary. The issue here is when I tested it separately somehow while converting this whole formula into a single cell, an additional '\' shows up. I cannot remove it. When tried .replace() method it removes all other double quotes too.

Comment: When I type =IFERROR(IF(OR(O2<>"",O2<>"NULL"),IF(OR(J2="Term 1",J2="Term 33"),O2+MIN(XLOOKUP(CONCAT(N2,C2,J2,H2),Subject_Map!$G:$G,Subject_Map!$H:$H,"",0),Raw(Merged)!S2),O2),O2),O2) in Excel, excel complains about the bracket in Raw(Merged). but maybe I misunderstood you.

Comment: The answer is correct, you do need quotes around the Sheet name when parentheses are in the name. You can easily check this by selecting any cell in the Sheet  'Raw(Merged)' e.g. 'A1', Copy the cell, then paste as a link into a cell in another Sheet. You will see the name is enclosed in quotes `='Raw(Merged)'!$A$1`. I tested your formula with this fix and the formula is written correctly and functions. If you are getting '\' in the formula it may be an attempt to delimit the parentheses.

Comment: I guess that is correct, maybe I missed about the brackets, but still I what I am stuck with is converting this whole formula into a single string so that I can pass to the xlwings sheet object to apply it.

Comment: To give an example check this fn, I need this formula as a single string, if you check the O/P there is an additional '\' coming.

def special2():
        
        f_string = f'''=IFERROR(IF(OR(O2<>"",O2<>"NULL"),IF(OR(J2="Term 1",J2="Term 33"),
        O2+MIN(XLOOKUP(CONCAT(N2,C2,J2,H2),Subject_Map!$G:$G,Subject_Map!$H:$H,"",0),
        'Raw(Merged)'!S2),O2),O2),O2)'''
        
        
        return (f_string)

Comment: This is the output of the fn above,
'=IFERROR(IF(OR(O2<>"",O2<>"NULL"),IF(OR(J2="Term 1",J2="Term 33"),O2+MIN(XLOOKUP(CONCAT(N2,C2,J2,H2),Subject_Map!$G:$G,Subject_Map!$H:$H,"",0),\'Raw(Merged)\'!S2),O2),O2),O2)'

Comment: It works for me: data_ws.range("P2:P4").formula = special2(). I just copy paste your special2() in my Clion. change nothing.

Comment: The additional '\' acts as an escape character in python. https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp